# Refresh jquery slider with select onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with several fields, including a jquery slider and a select dropdown box. Currently, when I change the selection of the dropdown, I clear the values of several other fields via the following javascript:

```
function clearVolumes() {
  document.getElementById('size').value = "";
  document.getElementById('amount').value = "";
  document.getElementById('hardwood_testet').value = "";
}
```

and I call this with the onchange:

```
<select id="catbiomass" name="categories[]" onchange="clearVolumes()" />
```

this is working great for me. However, there is a jquery slider in the form (that I found via SO) that I am also trying to refresh back to zero with this onchange, but with no luck. The jquery for the slider is:

```
$( "#hardwoodslider" ).slider({
  range: "min",
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  step: 5,
  value: 0.00,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
  $( "#hardwood_testet" ).val( ui.value );
  $(ui.value).val($('#hardwood_testet').val());
  }
  });
$("#hardwood_testet").keyup(function() {
  $("#hardwoodslider").slider("value" , $(this).val())
});
```

what I'm trying is to add the following jquery:

```
$("#catbiomass").onchange(function() {
  $("#hardwoodslider").slider("value" , 0)
});
```

this isn't working, when I change the select field the slider isn't being reset to zero. I have been reading around and this code should work, so is the problem because of the fact that I am in fact calling two onchange events in the select field, one via javascript and one via jquery?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried two possible solutions and both work fine for me:

1. Combine both onChange functions

   ```
   $("#catbiomass").onchange(function() {
       document.getElementById('size').value = "";
       document.getElementById('amount').value = "";
       document.getElementById('hardwood_testet').value = "";
       $("#hardwoodslider").slider("value" , 0)
   });
   ```

   or

   ```
   function clearVolumes() {
       document.getElementById('size').value = "";
       document.getElementById('amount').value = "";
       document.getElementById('hardwood_testet').value = "";
       $("#hardwoodslider").slider("value" , 0);
   }
   ```
2. Use ".bind" instead of ".onchange":

   ```
   $("#catbiomass").bind('change', function() {
       $("#hardwoodslider").slider("value" , 0);
   });
   ```

You can check out my demo [here](http://jsbin.com/yusedebalayu/1/).

Comment: Sebastian thank you for that, I went with the 2nd one and works like a charm.